# set options for MSVC preprocessor from command line arguments

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I am building a simple C++ application, required to use Visual C++ Build Tools from the command line, and sometimes the application is needed as Gui App and Sometimes as a Console App.

The control code for which version I generate is here:

```
int WinGUI = 1;
// The following if statement determines whether we are compiling a console
// application, like python.exe, or a windows gui application, like wpython.exe
#if WinGui == 1
int APIENTRY wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
) {
  // define aliases for the gui version of argc and argv
    int argc = __argc;
    wchar_t **argv = __wargv;
#else
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv) {
#endif
```

I have seen some posts on using CFLAGS with make files, but I am not certain how to translate that into what I am doing.

I have a batch script that sets up the environment and then builds this executable with this line:

```
cl /EHsc /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE %APPNAME%.cpp /Fe%APPNAME%
```

Is it possible to set a Comamnd line switch to control this preprocessor directive and thus to deterimine whether a commandline or gui version of the executable is built?

Comment: /DWinGui=1 ? PS: most of the time defines are all caps

Comment: @JVApen, I believe this is correct though I am working out a couple of bugs to make sure.  Thanks so much, you should post it as an answer to claim your prize

Comment: Application looks for a specific entry point. You need different link command: `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` for `wWinMain`, or `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` for `wmain` - Also change `int WinGUI = 1;` to `#define WinGUI`, and use `#ifdef WinGUI`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The linker will usually figure out the proper subsystem based on the presence of the various entry point functions.

Comment: Thanks for all three comments.  I did change the pattern to #define WinGUI, /DWinGui does work and the linker figures out automatically how to compile each one